# C issue: Program terminates itself

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


char choice;
struct {
    char name[20];
    int rn;
}read,write;

void wr(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("record.txt","a+");
    printf("Enter Your Name: ");
    scanf("%s",write.name);
    printf("Enter Your Roll Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&write.rn);

    fprintf(fp,"%s\t%d",write.name,write.rn);

    fclose(fp);

    menu();
}
void rd(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("record.txt","r");
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s %d",read.name,&read.rn)!= EOF){
        printf("%s\t%d\n",read.name,read.rn);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    getche();
    menu();
}

void menu(){
    system("cls");
    printf("Do you want to read/write/exit the data R/W/E: ");
    scanf("%c",&choice);
    tolower(choice);

    if(choice == 'w'){
        wr();
    }
    else if(choice == 'r'){
        rd();
    }
    else if(choice == 'e'){
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main() {

    menu();
    getche();
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to terminate it when user enters 'e' but it terminates after every information entry as well as I read data.

Means after every time read or write function works and the program should ask again about the choice it terminates.

Comment: What is 'getche()'?

Comment: ..also beware newline char left in buffer.

Comment: `fopen` can fail, you need to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `for` or a `while` loop like so:

```
int main() 
{
while(1) // while true
{
    menu();
    getche();
    system("cls");
}
return 0;
}
```

You are already calling `exit(1)` in your `else if` of `menu()`, so add the `while(true)` and it will work as you want it to.